# MFRC522 RFID module with flat cable as antenna

Tags: rfid

I saw a commercial product that used a "hacked" MFRC522 RFID module PCB (those cheap RC522 modules that you can find everywhere) and a long flat cable as antenna (like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Flat-Flex-Cable.jpg)) to obtain a long and narrow reading range. The embedded antenna on the original PCB was cut off, and in its place a 30 cm long flat cable (1 mm pitch, 30 pins) was somehow soldered to the module (via an adapter PCB). Looking at the schematic of the RC522 module, seems like a "custom" antenna could be connected to R6/R7 once you disconnect the embedded antenna.

[image]

I don't have any other insight on the design, so I'm trying to understand how the flat cable could be used as antenna. How would you wire the 30 pins? My only ideas were the following two (simplified to a 6-pins cable). Are there other ways? Which one would the be correct/more effective way of wiring it?

[image]

Also, I guess that all the surrounding components need to change in order to adapt to the new antenna, is that right? Do you think it is possible to calculate those parts without special equipment? I only have an oscilloscope and a digital multimeter.

Comment: NXP have a number of documents outlining how to design and test RFID antennas. As such, the ‘antenna’ is really the primary coil in an air cored transformer. Cheap devices like the NanoVNA can be used to tune the antenna. There’s nothing magic about using flat cable - it is just wire.

Comment: have you tested it? I have the same project for my rc and I ask myself exactly the same question... I ordered the cables and adapters